# Can I use typescript utility types with jsdoc?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, visual-studio-code, jsdoc

When I used jsdoc into vscode. I saw I could use typescript utility types.
For example:

```js
/**
 * Func 1
 * @param {number} x 
 */
function func1(x) {
    return [x, x]
}

/**
 * Func 2
 * @param {ReturnType<func1>} x  // Here !
 */
function func2(x) {
    return x[0];
}
```

So I wonder if this is a correct usage of jsodc.
And if there is a way to create my own type transformers, e.g. create one to unwrap promise resolve type.

Comment: It'll work because VSCode and VS uses the same engine for TypeScript and JavaScript, but if someone tries to use your code in an IDE that doesn't support TypeScript it won't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To create new a type transformer which unwrap promise :

```
/**
 * @template T
 * @typedef  {T extends Promise<infer Value> ? Value : T} PromiseValue
 */
```

Or with [type-fest](https://github.com/sindresorhus/type-fest) :

```
/**
 * @template T
 * @typedef {import('type-fest').PromiseValue<T>} PromiseValue 
 */
```